# How to make notification in slack if one of the step is cancelled by gitaction itself

Tags: github-actions

We have configured a notification if a job fails through git actions:

[image: steps]

However the problem is that as seen in screenshot even if the step is cancelled by gitactions (it could be due to some reasons), it will not go to the notification step?

What can we modify on the current setup so that the notification step will work?

Tried adding a notification step:

```
- name: Slack Notification Failure
  uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
```

Comment: I think it does